# Reading and storing values from csv file in an array using C

Tags: c, csv

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int c1[100];
    char c2[150];
    char c3[100];
    float c4[100];
    float c5[100];
    float c6[100];
    float c7[100];
    char c8[100];
    char c9[100];
    float c10[100];
    char string[10][100];
    int i, j;
    char c;

    FILE *fp1;
    fp1 = fopen("sample.csv", "r");
    while (1) {
        c = fgetc(fp1);
        if (c == EOF)
            break;
        else
            printf("%c", c);
    }

    for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        fscanf(fp1, "%d,%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%d,%d",
               &c1[i], &c2[i], &c3[i], &c4[i], &c5[i],
               &c6[i], &c7[i], &c8[i], &c9[i], &c10[i]);
    }

    for (j = 0; j <= 10; j++) {
        printf("\n");
        printf("%d", c3); //Here i am trying to read the column3 values but getting random integer values.
        //This problem continues to every column
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have to read file **sample.csv** and store values into the array so that I can perform operation on that values.
I am not getting the exact value from the csv file that I have read. 
I am getting some random integer value on running the program.

Comment: There are multiple issues with the program. You don't check if `fopen` was successful or not, `c` should be an `int` as `fgetc` returns an `int`, array indices in C begin from 0 not 1, you use `fscanf` _after_ you scanned all the characters in the file, `c3` is an array of `char` and yet you use `%d` as if it was an `int` etc. I suggest looking up on a good C tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply read a line in a loop until there are no more lines

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_ITEMS 10000
#define LARGEST_LINE 1000
#define LARGEST_ELEMENT 100

int main(void) {
    int c1[MAX_ITEMS];
    char c2[MAX_ITEMS][LARGEST_ELEMENT+1]; // large enough for each `c2`
    char c3[MAX_ITEMS][LARGEST_ELEMENT+1];
    char c4[MAX_ITEMS][LARGEST_ELEMENT+1];
    char c5[MAX_ITEMS][LARGEST_ELEMENT+1];
    int c6[MAX_ITEMS];
    int c7[MAX_ITEMS];

    int tmpc1;
    char tmpc2[LARGEST_ELEMENT+1];
    char tmpc3[LARGEST_ELEMENT+1];
    char tmpc4[LARGEST_ELEMENT+1];
    char tmpc5[LARGEST_ELEMENT+1];
    int tmpc6;
    int tmpc7;

    int lineno = 0;
    char buf[LARGEST_LINE]; // large enough for the largest line
    while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fp1)) {
        ++lineno;
        // no error, process line
        if (sscanf(buf, "%d,"
                        "%" LARGEST_ELEMENT "[^,],"
                        "%" LARGEST_ELEMENT "[^,],"
                        "%" LARGEST_ELEMENT "[^,],"
                        "%" LARGEST_ELEMENT "[^,],"
                        "%d,%d",
              &tmpd1, tmpc2, tmpc3, tmpc4, tmpc5, &tmpd6, &tmpd7) == 7) {
            // line ok, copy tmp variables and update indexes
            c1[i] = tmpd1;
            strcpy(c2[i], tmpc2);
            strcpy(c3[i], tmpc3);
            strcpy(c4[i], tmpc4);
            strcpy(c5[i], tmpc5);
            c6[i] = tmpd6;
            c7[i] = tmpd7;
            i++;
        } else {
            // line with error, you may want to report to the user
            fprintf(stderr, "line %d with error.\n", lineno);
        }
    }
    // read "error", probably EOF; close file and report
    fclose(fp1);
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        printf("item #%d: %d, %s-%s-%s-%s, %d %d\n",
              c1[j], c2[j], c3[j], c4[j], c5[j], c6[j], c7[j]);
    }
return 0;
}
```

Also consider putting all those c arrays inside a struct and make 1 single array of that structure.

Comment: This causes compilation errors: `"%" LARGEST_ELEMENT "[^,],"` You should either use a macro to stringize `LARGEST_ELEMENT` or use a different macro `S_LARGEST_ELEMENT` defined as `#define S_LARGEST_ELEMENT "100"`

Answer (score 1):

There are many problems in your code:

- you do not check if `fopen()` succeeded.
- `c` must be defined as `int` for proper end of file testing
- you must rewind the file with `rewind(fp1);` or `fseek(fp1, 0L, SEEK_SET);` before reparsing the contents with `fscanf()`
- the loop index `i` must start at `0` instead of `1`, because arrays are `0` based.
- it is idiomatic in C to use `for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) ...` to handle 10 lines of input. `i <= 10` would iterate 11 times.
- you must check the return value of `fscanf()` to ensure the input stream has the expected format. The format string does not handle empty text fields.
- the `fscanf()` format string is incompatible with the arguments provided
- the `printf` format string `"%d\n"` in incompatible with the type of the argument: the argument is the array `c3` which is passed as a pointer to its first member, not an `int` as expected.